# HP Laserjet 4000T prints PCL XL UnsupportedProtocol error

Tags: windows-10, tcpip, cups, hp-laserjet, print-drivers

I have a working CUPS setup, configured for a HP LaserJet 4000T printer.

It works fine from all stations, except Windows 10-x64.

There is no HP LJ 4000 printer in the list with installable printers, nor does HP supply any.

The questions is: which one to install?

Answer (score 0):

Found that HP has an universal printer driver.
However, that one cannot detect which type my printer is, nor does manually specifying the device type have any effect.

Settled on installing a LJ-4050 printer PS driver instead, which seems to work but does not match the hardware.